# To make a column consecutive in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have this MySQL table:

```
LOT_LOCATION, Zone Attribute, LOTID, Design_ID, Board_ID1, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO, QA_CONTACT_NAME
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVRYHL2.11', 'FS196', '', '110811', 'WENGXINCHAN'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVQYHL2.11', 'FS196', '', '110811', 'WENGXINCHAN'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVQRHL2.11', 'B58R', '', '109640', 'TUNELITING'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVPYHL2.11', 'FS196', '', '110811', 'WENGXINCHAN'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVKYHL2.11', 'NM109', '', '', 'JFAJARDO'
```

What I want to do is to make the column QA_CONTACT_NAME consecutive based on the names:

```
LOT_LOCATION, Zone Attribute, LOTID, Design_ID, Board_ID1, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO, QA_CONTACT_NAME
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVRYHL2.11', 'FS196', '', '110811', 'WENGXINCHAN'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVQYHL2.11', 'FS196', '', '110811', 'WENGXINCHAN'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVPYHL2.11', 'FS196', '', '110811', 'WENGXINCHAN'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVKYHL2.11', 'NM109', '', '', 'JFAJARDO'
'SGBAKE.0011', '', 'CVQRHL2.11', 'B58R', '', '109640', 'TUNELITING'
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Use the `ORDER BY` clause of your SELECT statement.

Comment: Just [sort the rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)?

Comment: @IVOGELOV i have missed this out thanks!